# Write a big sql query or handle it through code?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have 2 tables built in this way:

```
Trips
- id
- organization_id REQUIRED
- collaboration_organization_id OPTIONAL
...other useless fields...

Organizations
- id
- name REQUIRED
...other useless fields...
```

Now I have been asked to create this type of report:

> I want the sum of all trips for each organization, considering that if
>   they have a collaboration_organization_id it should count as 0.5,
>   obviusly the organization in collaboration_organization_id get a +0.5
>   too

So whenever I have a trip that has organization_id AND collaboration_organization_id set, that trip count as 0.5 for both organizations. If instead only organization_id is set, it counts as 1.

Now my question is composed by two parts:

**1.**

> Is a good idea to "solve" the problem all in SQL?

I already know how to solve it through code, my idea is currently "select all trips (only those 3 fields) and start counting in ruby". Please consider that I'm using ruby on rails so could still be a good reason to say "no because it will work only on mysql".

**2.**

> If point 1 is YES, I have no idea how to count for 0.5 each trip where it's required, because count is a "throw-in-and-do-it" function

Comment: it's a good idea to do as much in the DB as possible. count() can be faked with `sum(if(...your credit logic here...))` as well.

Comment: That is important, thanks. Didn't think about "sum"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with ruby on rails, but this is how you can do this with MySQL.

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Trips(
  id int not null primary key,
  organization_id int not null,
  collaboration_organization_id int null
  );

INSERT INTO Trips (id,organization_id,collaboration_organization_id)
VALUES
(1,1,5),
(2,1,1),
(3,1,2),
(4,11,1),
(5,1,null),
(6,2,null),
(7,10,null),
(8,6,2),
(9,1,3),
(10,1,4);
```

MySQL Query:

```
SELECT organization_id,
sum(CASE WHEN collaboration_organization_id IS null THEN 1 ELSE 0.5 End) AS number
FROM Trips
GROUP BY organization_id;
```

Try it out via: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b01d/107

**EDIT: adding collaboration organization**

Sample data:

```
  CREATE TABLE Trips(
  id int not null primary key,
  organization_id int not null,
  collaboration_organization_id int null
  );

INSERT INTO Trips (id,organization_id,collaboration_organization_id)
VALUES
(1,1,5),
(2,1,1),
(3,1,2),
(4,11,1),
(5,1,null),
(6,2,null),
(7,10,null),
(8,6,2),
(9,1,3),
(10,1,4);


CREATE TABLE Organizations(
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  name varchar(30)
  );

INSERT INTO Organizations (name)
VALUES
("Org1"),
("Org2"),
("Org3"),
("Org4"),
("Org5"),
("Org6"),
("Org7"),
("Org8"),
("Org9"),
("Org10"),
("Org11"),
("Org12"),
("Org13"),
("Org14"),
("Org15"),
("Org16");
```

MySQL query:

```
SELECT O.id, O.name,
sum(CASE WHEN T.collaboration_organization_id IS null THEN 1 ELSE 0.5 End) AS number
FROM Organizations AS O LEFT JOIN Trips AS T  
ON T.organization_id = O.id OR T.collaboration_organization_id = O.id
WHERE T.collaboration_organization_id = O.id OR O.id = T.organization_id
GROUP BY O.id;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee557/15

Comment: SQL Fiddle... Didn't know about it, cool. However, your answer is good but the main point now is another: what if an organization does only trips in "collaboration", so it never appears as organization_id but only as collaboration_organization_id. I should still find the sum for that organization, with this query won't appear.

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL Agree SQL Fiddle is a great why to easily show how something works. 

Back to the topic. How will you deal with trips with more than 2 organizations? I would suggest to move the collaboration_organization_id and organization_id to an new table called trip_participants which contains all organizations that will be part of the trip.

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL I have added the collaborating organizations to the query see the edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've never done such a query, O.o And I didn't split them to "table_partecipants" due to the fact that they specified they will have a maximum of 2 partecipants (the main is forced, the second is optional). Thanks a lot anyway, very detailed answer.

Comment: I had never done a query like this before either, but I like a challenge. :-) The best of luck with your project.

Comment: Thanks a lot, well I never done it but I also didn't have any idea on how to do it. I'm definitely not strong on joins